# How do you disable elasticsearch dynamic mapping in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

In the elasticsearch.org website it states that you can set the default dynamic mapping to be false via `index.mapper.dynamic`.  Do I create a `tire` file in the initializers folder to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.Just use this style to create your mapping

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

    settings
         :mapper => {
           "dynamic" => "false"
         } do
      mapping { indexes :bar, :type => 'string', :analyzer => "url_analyzer" }
    end
end
```